# Updating a multivalue field in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm new to Solr, so I may be doing things incorrectly. As of now I add a document like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/update?commitWithin=100" --data-binary "[{'id': 'p1','name': {'set': 'my first product'}}]"
```

This works from what I can see and if I query using *:* I see the document as expected:

```
{
  "id":"p1",
  "name":"my first product",
  "_version_":1777204130233712640
}
```

I then try to add a multivalue field like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/update?commitWithin=100" --data-binary "[{'id':'p1','held_between': {'add': '[2023-06-01T00:00:00Z TO 2023-01-09T23:59:59Z]'}}]"
```

However, when I do that and query using *:* I end up with two documents that look like this:

```
{
  "add":["[2023-06-01T00:00:00Z TO 2023-01-09T23:59:59Z]"],
  "id":"p1/held_between#",
  "_version_":1777204285167108096
},
{
  "id":"p1",
  "_version_":1777204285167108096
}
```

I'm expecting to see something like this:

```
{
  "id":"p1",
  "name":"my first product",
  "held_between":"[2023-06-01T00:00:00Z TO 2023-01-09T23:59:59Z]"
  "_version_":1777204130233712640
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `add` was added to the schema at some point as a TextField and that was causing all the issues. Deleting the field from the schema fixed my problem.